# How to use log power in python?

Tags: python, logging

If I am asked to have P(t)=log(V(t)I(t)) where log is natural log to base e. V(t) stands for voltage and I(t) stands for current.
In my programme, I should type in

```
def logpower(voltage,current):
    p = math.log(voltage*current,math.e)
    return p
```

or

```
def logpower(voltage,current):
    p = math.log(voltage*current)
    return p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log

> **math.log(x[, base])**
>
> With one argument, return the natural logarithm of x (to base e).
>
> With two arguments, return the logarithm of x to the given base,
> calculated as log(x)/log(base).

So both of your examples are correct but `p = math.log(voltage*current)` looks much clearer